# How to split the strings in vc++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a string "stack+ovrflow*newyork;" i have to split this stack,overflow,newyork

any idea??

Comment: Which string class are you using? or is this a char*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First and foremost if available, I would always use boost::tokenizer for this kind of task (see and upvote the great answers below)

Without access to boost, you have a couple of options:

You can use C++ std::strings and parse them using a stringstream and getline (safest way)

```
std::string str = "stack+overflow*newyork;";
std::istringstream stream(str);
std::string tok1;
std::string tok2;
std::string tok3;

std::getline(stream, tok1, '+');
std::getline(stream, tok2, '*');
std::getline(stream, tok3, ';');

std::cout << tok1 << "," << tok2 << "," << tok3 << std::endl
```

Or you can use one of the strtok family of functions (see Naveen's answer for the unicode agnostic version; see xtofls comments below for warnings about thread safety), if you are comfortable with char pointers

```
char str[30]; 
strncpy(str, "stack+overflow*newyork;", 30);

// point to the delimeters
char* result1 = strtok(str, "+");
char* result2 = strtok(str, "*");
char* result3 = strtok(str, ";");

// replace these with commas
if (result1 != NULL)
{
   *result1 = ',';
}
if (result2 != NULL)
{
   *result2 = ',';
}

// output the result
printf(str);
```

Comment: when using strtok, beware of it's single-theadedness!

Comment: @xtofl beware of any part of the STL and its single threadedness

Comment: @Doug T: if I'm correct, `strtok` is using the same global memory for any thread, whereas you can _choose_ to use e.g. different `string` objects in different threads.  And if you don't, you're screwed too.

Comment: @xtofl I'm not quite sure I understand what you're saying. None of the standard library of C or C++ is thread safe... Neither language has any concept of threading built into the language itself. But maybe I'm not following you exactly.

Comment: @Doug T: `strtok` is stateful, while `getline` uses the argument object's state.  I imagined above code were wrapped into two functions.  The function with `stringstream` uses local variables and thus is thread safe.  The `strtok` version, even though it _appears_ to use thread-local variables, will cause race conditions since `strtok` is stateful.  (cfr http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

[Boost tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html)

Simple like this:

```
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
std::string stringToTokenize= "stack+ovrflow*newyork;";
boost::char_separator<char> sep("+*;");
boost::tokenizer< boost::char_separator<char> > tok(stringToTokenize, sep);
std::vector<std::string> vectorWithTokenizedStrings;
vectorWithTokenizedStrings.assign(tok.begin(), tok.end());
```

Now vectorWithTokenizedStrings has the tokens you are looking for. Notice the boost::char_separator variable. It holds the separators between the tokens.

Answer (score 4):

See boost tokenizer [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [_tcstok](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb(VS.80).aspx) to tokenize the string based on a delimiter.

Comment: What's the difference between _tcstok and strtok?

Comment: It will call either strtok or wcstok depnding on whether UNICODE compiler flag is set or not during compliation.

Answer (score 2):

This site has a string tokenising function that takes a string of characters to use as delimiters and returns a vector of strings.

[Simple STL String Tokenizer Function](http://www.digitalpeer.com/id/simple)

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to split a string using c/c++ :

First define a function to split a string:

```
//pointers of the substrings, assume the number of fields will not be over 5
char *fields[5];   
//str: the string to splitted
//splitter: the split charactor
//return the real number of fields or 0 if any error exits
int split(char* str, char *splitter)
{
    if(NULL == str) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int cnt;
    fields[0] = str;
    for(cnt = 1; (fields[cnt] = strstr(fields[cnt - 1], splitter)) != NULL && 
            cnt < 5; cnt++)
    {
        *fields[cnt] = '\0';
        ++fields[cnt];
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

then you can use this function to split string as following:

```
char* str = "stack+ovrflow*newyork;"
split(str, "+");
printf("%s\n", fields[0]); //print "stack"
split(fields[1], "*");
printf("%s\n", fields[0]); //print "ovrflow"
split(fields[1], ";");
printf("%s\n", fields[0]); //print "newyork"
```

this way will be more efficient and reusable

Comment: Your function returns an natural number (a counter), not a real number. Thanks for the answer!