# std::getline read the last string twice

Tags: c++

Test file wrote like

```
   Sat Aug 10 22:03:09 2019
   Test completed
```

First i used in.eof(), but someone told me do never use thoes in.eof().

```
enter code here
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  //test.txt is a test file. 
  std::ifstream in("test.txt");

if (!in.is_open()) {
   std::cout << "file not found" << std::endl;
return 0;
}

std::string s;
while (in) {
getline(in, s);
std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I'd expect the result like

```
   Sat Aug 10 22:03:09 2019
   Test completed
```

But the result is

```
   Sat Aug 10 22:03:09 2019
   Test completed
   Test completed
```

Comment: Try `while(getline(in, s))` instead of `while (in) { getline(in, s)...`.

Comment: getline doesn't read the last line twice, the last getline fails, leaving the `s` variable unchanged. Fix your loop and the problem will go away.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. \`while (!stream.eof())\`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this part of the code, just after the last successful read:

```
while (in) {          // succeeds
    std::getline(in, s);   // fails (EOF), and s is unchanged
```

This is exactly equivalent to [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](/q/5605125/4850040).

The fix is to make the `getline()` result part of the condition:

```
while(std::getline(in, s)) {
```

Comment: Thx, very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do what you want is

`for (std::string s; std::getline(in, s);)`

The issue may be related with the new line symbol (`\n`) at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Loop while `getline` is successfull and not while the `istream` is valid.

```
while (getline(in, s)) {
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }
```