# how to split cin input

Tags: c++, cin

I am facing problem to split my input in C++, for something similar to the Python split function.
The input is given as 1001-43 1003-45 1008-67 in different lines. I want to know how to take these inputs split by `'-'` and store them in different variables.

In Python it's:

```
a, x = input().split('-')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split the strings in vc++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044088/how-to-split-the-strings-in-vc)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at boost. The [string algorithms library](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.boost.org%2Fdoc%2Flibs%2F1_49_0%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Fstring_algo.html&ei=ZhHwT_LvJYy78gPHzI2SDQ&usg=AFQjCNEfJw3oBaHdEmu3fXa3qx5PoITHSQ&sig2=o3hwZDb0fCuM6zuD8Qq53Q) includes most of what you can find in python including a split function which splits a string into an stl container of your choice. For example (lifted from their docs) splitting on dash or asterisk:

```
std::string str1("hello abc-*-ABC-*-aBc goodbye");

std::vector< std::string > SplitVec; // #2: Search for tokens
split( SplitVec, str1, is_any_of("-*"), token_compress_on );

// SplitVec == { "hello abc","ABC","aBc goodbye" }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int number,digit1,digit2,digit3;
std::cin>>number;
digit1=number%10;
digit2=number%100;
digit3=number%1000;
```

Comment: add explanation to your answer, this will help OP to understand.

Answer (score -2):

Check out strtok(), http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Comment: Personally, I think that `strtok` is a very bad recommendation because of its legacy non-reentrant interface.

Comment: `strtok` is a good recommendation for C, but not necessarily for idiomatic C++.

Comment: `strtok` is super-super-awful